# Why can't I see the symbol of new polygon object in my custom toolbar

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, toolbar

I have added a number of function in a custom toolbar with the plugin Customize Toolbars but two functions doesn't show up but they are still chosen? What am I doing wrong?

The two is (1) add a new polyline-object and (2) add a new polygon-object (marked in the picture below)[image: screendump]

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing anything wrong. In QGIS, only one layer can be active at a time. Some buttons on toolbars are hidden or visible, depending on the geometry type of the active layer.

For example, I've added three buttons to the custom toolbar using Customize ToolBars plugin as in the image.

[image]

But in reality, just one button appears on the toolbar based on the geometry type of the selected layer.

[image]

Comment: Well, that was my idea first, but regardless of which layer I have chosen or if it was in edit mode I cant see the symbols

Comment: If i remove the symbol save and then add the symbol again so is it working (but the symbols are not correctly placed) until i restart qgis then the symbols is gone again